# How to extract the unique variance of a variable

Tags: correlation, variance

Is there any procedure to quickly obtain the variance that is unique to a variable among a correlated group of variables?

For example a star's temperature mass and volume are related (3 variables), bigger starts tend to have more mass and be hotter. I can perform multiple linear regression of 1 variable using the other 2 as predictors (mass against temperature and volume, volume against temperature and mass...), the residuals can be stored as new variables, these residuals will have no correlation with the other variables (predictors) except with the associated predicted variable (so 3 new variables residual for mass, temperature and volume, each one correlated with mass temperature and volume respectively but not with the other 2). The problem is that I have to repeat this process many times, for each dependent variable I want to get the unique variance of. Is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean?  This sounds a bit like an effort to allocate components of a response to individual explanatory variables in a multiple regression, but that's not evident, nor does it usually make any sense.

Comment: @whuber In a group of correlated variables, there is shared variance. I want to get rid of it, to see the actual values of the variables that are "unique" to them.  For example a star's temperature mass and volume are related, bigger starts tend to have more mass and be hotter, because of this, these variables are just showing me a common factor in a way, I would like to see the values in temperature, for example, that are not explained by the rest, its unique variance. Distil them.

Comment: "Not explained by the rest" sounds like you might want to perform a multiple regression of temperature against the other variables.  Another possibility is that you want to perform some kind of PCA or factor analysis of all the variables.  It remains difficult to understand your objective with sufficient clarity to be able to translate it into a definite recommendation.

Comment: @whuber yes, multiple linear regression and storing residuals seems good. the problem is that it is slow to perform, specially when there are many different variables. although the relationship migh not be linear.

Comment: i was wondering if there is a standard way of doing this. On the surface seems very simple.

Comment: I don't follow, because the algorithms behind linear regression and PCA and its relatives are efficient and can handle thousands of variables easily.  Your reference to "not be linear" changes the subject, because variance is basically a linear concept.  I am left still wondering what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @whuber yes, you can add as many predictors as you want for linear regression. But you can only make models for 1 dependent variable, so you have to repeat the regression for each variable in order to get its unique variance, thats why it is slow. And the relationship between variables might not be linear, even though each variance is, but thats something else. Maybe with PCA it could be done easily, but I'm not aware how.

Comment: Perhaps you could give an example of what you would do with one dependent variable and then explain what you want to do in an extension to multiple dependent variables. Please include this information in an edit to the original post and not just in the comments.

Comment: @whuber For example, using the same example about stars I gave earlier, you could extract the unique variance of the variable "temperature" by performing multiple linear regression (I usually do something else when is not linear but I wont explain it for simplicity's sake) using volume and mass as predictors, then take the residuals as a new variable. This new variable will have very low, or almost none correlation with the other 2, repeat this process with volume and mass, and you have the unique variance of each variable, variance independent from the others, more or less.

Comment: Re "repeat the regression:" I don't think that's the case.  There are far more efficient methods for analyzing the covariance matrix of all the variables.  (Good keywords include QR decomposition and Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.)  If you're concerned about nonlinear relationships, you're not asking the right questions.

Comment: Re the edit: this sounds like you are asking how to compute the [partial correlation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation).